# Segue from UICollectionViewCell xib to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have UICollectionViewCell (Paging enabled, width & height equal to view) which have another UICollectionView (2nd level, which is added programatically) inside cell. 2nd level UICollectionView has  UICollectionViewCell using xib(CustomMenuViewController). 
In this xib file, I have a button, by pressing this button I want to go to another UIViewController.

```
class Cellnew: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    let cellId = "mycell";

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);

        setupViews();
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "subMenuCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "mycell")
           }

    lazy var menuBar : MenuBar = {
        let mb = MenuBar()
        return mb

    }()

    func setupViews(){
        addSubview(collectionView);

        collectionView.delegate = self;
        collectionView.dataSource = self;

        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true;
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true;
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true;
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true


    }

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 30
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical; //set scroll direction to horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout);
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "F9F9F9")
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        cv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 150, 0)

        return cv;
    }();


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell : subMenuCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! subMenuCollectionViewCell

        cell.mImagePress.addTarget(self,action:#selector(self.toCustommenu), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell;
        }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 10, 20, 10);
                }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5;
                }



  @objc func toCustommenu(){

      //What can i do here


                }




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.reloadData()
        print("menutapped")
        let myDict: [String: Any] = ["CellNo": indexPath.row]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .refresh, object: myDict)


    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:( self.frame.width/2)-10-10, height: self.frame.height/3);
    }
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can perfrom a segue from a UIViewController to another one. You need at some point to tell the parent ViewController (so if I understood, CollectionViewCollectionViewViewController, using closure, delegate as you wish) to perform the segue.

Comment: can u give me code ? I m new ios app development  I dont have uiviewcontroller object there . I m in xib file (self of xib i have there)

Comment: Your first collection view displaying - view controller is in the storyboard?

Comment: Then, connect a segue from that view controller to your destination view controller. On button click from xib, call a delegate method to the view controller and perform the segue.

Comment: @MBN can u give me sample code for delegate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Connect a segue from parentViewController to destinationViewController.

2.Parent View Controller

```
class parentViewcontroller : ViewController , ParentCellProtocol
{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

    {
        Create instance of cell - parentCollectionViewCell
        //Set the delegate
        parentCollectionViewCell.parentDelegate = self
    }

    //Implement the ParentCellProtocol delegate method
    func buttonClickedFromParentCell()
    {
        //Perform segue here
    }
}
```

3.Parent Custom cell

```
protocol ParentCellProtocol 
   {
      func buttonClickedFromParentCell()
   }

   class ParentCell : ChildCellProtocol
   {
      //Create an instance of protocol.
      var parentDelegate : ParentCellProtocol?

      //Implement ChildCellProtocol Method
      func buttonClickedFromChild(){

         parentDelegate.buttonClickedFromParentCell()
      }


      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
      {
         Create instance of cell - childCustomCell
         //Set the delegate
         childCustomCell. childDelegate = self
      }
   }
```

4.Child Custom cell

```
protocol ChildCellProtocol {
    func buttonClickedFromChild()
}

class ChildCell
{
    //Create an instance of protocol.
    var childDelegate : ChildCellProtocol?

    //call the delegate method on button click.
    func toCustommenu(){

        //What can i do here
        childDelegate.buttonClickedFromChild()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: thanks for help . but collectionview of cellnew is loaded in another parentcollectionviewcell. what can i do now?

Comment: You can follow the same procedure there also.

Comment: [viewcontroller 
   [collectionview  [collectionviewcell 
          [collectionview [collectionviewcell[xib]  ]]]]] this is view hierarchy                         now you can help me? self object , i want from viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have an initial `UIViewController` that contains the outermost collection view inside a storyboard. I'm also assuming this is the view that should transition to another view controlled by a second `UIViewController`.

Since you are working programmatically inside the collection view, your best bet would most likely be creating a segue from the initial view controller to the secondary view controller and triggering it by name.

To do this:

1. Locate the initial view controller and secondary view controller on the storyboard.
2. Control-drag from the yellow circle on the top bar of the initial view controller to the secondary view.
3. From the pop-up menu, under "Manual Segue", select the correct option, likely to be "Show".
4. Click on the segue that is created and give it an identifier.
5. In your code, whenever you want to perform the transition, call [`performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) (passing in the identifier string you specified for the segue) on the `UIViewController` the outermost collection view is contained in.

Comment: thanks .. I dont have any initial viewcontroller. Button i triggered is on xib which is not part of storyboard.

Comment: Ok... I think the reason they implemented storyboards in the first place is to ease situations like these. If you're using swift I assume you are not working with legacy code so I'd encourage you to look into them.